# Firebase Cloud Function deploy tslint error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I started a new Firebase project with the CLI.
I'm using only Cloud functions and wanted to deploy some functions 
but Im getting this error

```
functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
```

I already changed following lines:

```
  "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
  "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
```

to

```
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
```

because they also threw an error.

What do I need to change?

Edit:

I created a new Firebase project (In a folder called Firebase) with the cli and only use Cloud functions.
Then I copied all my .ts files into the src folder and added my dependencies.

```
 "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
 "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
 "@types/async": "^2.0.48",
 "@types/camelcase": "^4.1.0",
 "@types/glob": "^5.0.35",
 "@types/request": "^2.47.0",
 "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.2",
 "async": "^2.6.0",
 "camelcase": "^4.1.0",
 "glob": "^7.1.2",
 "install": "0.10.4",
 "npm": "5.6.0",
 "request": "^2.85.0",
 "xml2js": "^0.4.19"
```

Then I run firebase deploy and got the following:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! path C:\...\Projects\Firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\Projects\Firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\...\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-19T20_48_36_986Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238

C:\...\Projects\Firebase>
```

The log file showed:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '%RESOURCE_DIR%',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\Projects\Firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
5 verbose cwd C:\...\Projects\Firebase
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "%RESOURCE_DIR%" "run" "lint"
8 verbose node v8.9.4
9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
10 error path C:\...\Projects\Firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -4058
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\Projects\Firebase\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I just edited the directory paths where necessary.

Comment: That line you're showing isn't an error line.  That's just telling you that tslint about to be run against your project.  What's the real error message here?

Comment: I updated my question with the console and log details.

Comment: What version of the Firebase CLI?

Comment: C:\>firebase -V
3.18.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I created another new project which uses hosting and functions.
I got the same error as above. After searching again I found this solution.
In the firebase.json file I replaced

```
"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
```

with

```
 "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
    ]
  }
```

After reading [this issues on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610)

Comment: Hi. As you found the solution could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 5):

What it worked for me was delete node_modules from 'functions' folder and then install everything again. I think I should have tried this first instead of something else. Of course, make sure you have tslint dependency installed.

Answer (score 2):

reinitialize firebase in your project

```
firebase init
```