# Invalid option for project: tslint.json in flutter's project

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter

I tried the command firebase deploy --only functions in Android Studio, while using flutter.
At first, it showed no error, than i don't know why, one day it started showing it. And after that, it continues. Can anyone explain me this error, and try to tell me how to fix it.

=== Deploying to 'social-media-clone-app'...

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\Hp\AndroidStudioProjects\social_app\functions
> tslint -p tslint.json

Invalid option for project: tslint.json
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint -p tslint.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-03T18_53_59_935Z-debug.log
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Here's my package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true

}
```

(P.S. I have edited the versions of node to 8 and firebase_admin and firebase_functions too)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915952/firebase-cloud-function-deploy-tslint-error

Comment: @Phix It didn't worked.